# Getting Distinct Keys with Inner Join

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-in

I have the below code attempting to get distinct nm.key entries, along with the other specified columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT nm.key, nt.nt, pd.r, pd.b, pd.s
FROM nm
    INNER JOIN nt ON 
    nm.nkey==nt.nkey

    INNER JOIN pd ON 
    pd.key==nm.key


   
WHERE nt.nt RLIKE "pain"
```

It is not returning distinct nm.key when I run this. Does anyone know why? Also, would anyone know why the "WHERE" statement is not working

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the below code attempting to get distinct nm.key entries, along with the other specified columns

`SELECT DISTINCT` gives you distinct *rows*.  If your query is returning more than one row with the same `nm.key`, then it must be that they differ in one or more of the other columns.

And that belies a conceptual or design problem.  Evidently, `nm.key` is not sufficient to uniquely identify values for all the other selected columns, so which values of the other columns do you want?

> Also, would anyone know why the "WHERE" statement is not working

For one thing, you're using the wrong quotes.  Char and varchar literals are expressed in single quotes in standard SQL:

```sql
WHERE nt.nt RLIKE 'pain'
```

But also, `RLIKE` performs a regular-expression match (at least in MySQL, to which it seems to be idiosyncratic). Your pattern is a simple string.  You can use that as a regex, but it would be equivalent and clearer to just use `=`, like so:

```sql
WHERE nt.nt = 'pain'
```

Comment: How would you suggest only selecting distinct for nm.key

Comment: How would you suggest only selecting distinct for nm.key

Comment: @power_of_epi, if you want the distinct values of `nm.key`, then `SELECT DISTINCT nm.key FROM [...]`.  Under some circumstances, you would not even need the `DISTINCT` part for that.  However, if you want distinct values of `nm.key` *plus* values for some other columns then again, you have a problem: `nm.key` does not uniquely identify a set of other values, so you need to decide how to determine which set of other values you want.